# how to pick a random image from the DCIM directory to set it as wallpaper?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with picking randomly an image from the DCIM directory.

Here is my code (in MainActivity.java):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random ran;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
                File imagedir = new File(secStore + "/DCIM");
                int totalNumFiles = imagedir.listFiles().length;   //nb of files in DCIM
                //we pick up one randomly
                ran = new Random();
                int indice = ran.nextInt(totalNumFiles) + 1;

                Bitmap bitmap = imagedir[indice];
                WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
//              Toast.makeText(context, "WP set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and in the manifest, I have declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The activity_main.xml has nothing on it.

My problem:

Bitmap bitmap = imagedir[indice];

I can't succeed to make the bridge between the random and the bitmap.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: `Bimap bitmap = imagedir.listFiles()[indice];`

Comment: But... there are mostly not many images in DCIM directory. DCIM/Camera has more.

Comment: `String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
                File imagedir = new File(secStore + "/DCIM");` Bad code. Replace by `File imagedir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`

Comment: And.. the DCIM directory contains subdirs. You will set a subdir as bitmap?

Comment: Thanks blackapps. Here the answers: 1/done but I get an error that `Required type:
Bitmap and Provided is: File`; 2&4/ in the current case, the DCIM has no subdirectory and has only images; 3/thanks, I replaced the code and it is fine. ---- so any idea for 1/ ?

Comment: Ha ha you put me wrong there. Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.loadFromFile (.......): Use the file from the indice.

Comment: loadFromFile (or LoadFromFile) is red and the error says: Cannot resolve method 'loadFromFile' in 'BitmapFactory'. I searched for this error code but could not find something. Anything else? --- Moreover my phone has deviceSDK API22 and the code is minSDK API23. I changed that in build.gradle but more errors are coming. Is there some code part that is API23 and can be written in API22 or what would be a possible solution?

Comment: If you type BitmapFactory. and then wait the Android Studio ide shows you all possible methods.

Comment: It is .decodeFile()! You should have de discovered that.

Comment: I am coding, not guessing. The philosophy itself is not simple. And actually I did find it, the correct syntax btw is: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(imagedir.listFiles()[indice]));`

Comment: No. The correct statement is `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagedir.listFiles()[indice].getAbsolutePath());` and you were told that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it works now and I have found a solution to my two problems:

- minSDK API23 to API22:
  the simplest was to recreate a totally new project with the right minSDK API22 from scratch to get rid of that point. Java indicates then that getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated but the code below fully works.
- right code:
  Here it is:

---

```
package com.example.randomwallpaper;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random ran;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        File imagedir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        int totalNumFiles = imagedir.listFiles().length;   //nb of files in DCIM
        //we pick up one randomly
        ran = new Random();
        int indice = ran.nextInt(totalNumFiles) + 1;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(imagedir.listFiles()[indice]));
        WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        try {
            manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WP set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Each time you launch the app, the wallpaper is randomly changed. The images are stored in the DCIM directory. There are only images and no subdirectory in the DCIM directory. Don't forget to declare the user's permissions in the manifest.