# Sending a URI from one method to another one

Tags: java, android, uri

A URI is got through this known code in the following method as data.getData():

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 8010:
            Log.i("Test", "Result URI " + data.getData());
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, there is another method (e.g. `public void dosomething() {}`) in the whole code where the URI is needed.

How can one get the URI, i.e. `data.getData()`, in `dosomething()`?

The use of `data.getData()` was tried in `dosomething()` without success. What works easily with standard variables normally, seems not to work with Uris.

ADDENDUM

Here a concrete example of code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void dosomething() {
        [--- here I need to get my data.getData() from onActivityResult()  (directory chosen by user in startChoose()) --- something like: mypath = data.getData();  ---]
        File imagedir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mypath);
        [...]
}


    public void startChoose(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose directory"), 8010);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch(requestCode) {
            case 8010:
                Log.i("Test", "Result URI " + data.getData());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

User action:
A user choose a directory by clicking a button, which leads to `startChoose()` with `onClick="startChoose"` in the XML. `onActivityResult()` gives access to the chosen directory (`=data.getData()`) and this path shall be used in `dosomething()` but I don't succeed at getting the chosen directory (`=data.getData()`) in `dosomething()`.

PS: `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` is deprecated but so far it can be used here (or you can update it as per API 29 if you want).

Basically, what I need is that the user chooses his/her directory by clicking on a button and based of that directory, the code continue its execution in `dosomething()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it `public void dosomething (Uri uri)` .

Comment: Thanks - I did so, but it doesn't work. It says _Cannot resolve method 'getData'_ when I have `variable = data.getData();` in `dosomething(Uri uri)`. Any idea?

Comment: ??? You should call it like `dosomething(data.getData());`. Well if in the same class. You did not tell so much.. post complete code. How and where defined and how and where called.

Comment: @blackapps : I added some more explanation.

Comment: You are not calling dosomething in onActivityResult. And you did not add the Uri parameter. Dont declare dosomething public as it makes no sense.

Comment: Listen: I don't want to expand dosomething() onActivityResult. I want the user to choose a directory in dosomething() and have this directory in the variable mypath. So I wonder why this is so complicated - perhaps better to leave it here.

Comment: @blackapps : [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64014564/how-to-pick-a-random-image-from-the-dcim-directory-to-set-it-as-wallpaper) you told me how to pick the directory DCIM with `File imagedir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`. What if the user wants to choose his own directory with `startChoose()` and `onActivityResult()` above? How can you combine both? Because `onActivityResult()` sends a Uri back whereas your code needs a String, i.e. an `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`.

Comment: It seems i told you how to construct a FIle object (or a path) for the DCIM directory. That has nothing to do with picking. Now if the user chooses/picks a diffferent directory. Lets say the user picks ..Pictures/Screenshots. Then tell how you would combine that with that DCIM. I have no idea where you are after. Further you are still nowhere calling dosomething. And it is still public which makes no sense. I saiud that before.

Answer (score 0):

ok, after searching for a while, I found the following to transmit the Uri via methods:

The class must begin with this variable declaration:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Uri mypath;
```

onActivityResult can be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 8010:
            mypath=data.getData();
            break;
    }
}
```

And then, you can use everywhere in the code the variable `mypath` as following:

```
 File mydirectory = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mypath.toString());
```

But mypath is the complete path of the directory and needs to be reduced to the environment path in order to work here. That's another game.